# docker-compose does not return an error as defined by the compose spec in terms of depends_on and profiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am currently going through the compose specification (for the purpose of learning). The compose specification on [profiles](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#profiles) defines that:

> References to other services (by links, extends or shared resource syntax service:xxx) MUST not automatically enable a component that would otherwise have been ignored by active profiles. Instead, the Compose implementation MUST return an error.

I currently have the below compose file which satisfies the above statement, when I do `docker-compose --profile debug up` docker-compose starts the `foo` service, the `zot` service. docker-compose should return an error (since I am not explicitly specifying that it should also enable the `bar` service, which `zot` depends on)

```yaml
services:
  foo:
    image: alpine
    container_name: foo
  bar:
    image: alpine
    container_name: bar
    profiles:
      - test
  baz:
    image: alpine
    depends_on:
      - bar
    profiles:
      - test
  zot:
    image: alpine
    depends_on:
      - bar
    profiles:
      - debug
```

Is this a bug or docker-compose implementation does not fully adhere to the compose specification?

Comment: I may be wrong but here is saying that `by links, extends or shared resource syntax service:xxx`. In other way you using `depends_on`. Here is no `links:` and `extends:` in your yaml `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: if you read further down the profiles section, you will see a statement like this `If profile debug is enabled, model contains both foo and zot services, but not bar and baz and as such the model is invalid regarding the depends_on constraint of zot.` @rzlvmp